# Has anyone ever used Felix Cloud Storage on heroku?

Tags: heroku, storage

[Felix Cloud Storage](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/felix) is a heroku add-on which lets you store files based on AWS S3.
On the free tier you get up to 100 GB-Mo Shared Storage (monthly)

It looks like there is enough space on the shared bucket and therefore I should be able
to upload at least a file.
[image]

The issue I have is that when I try to create a shared space, it will throw an error:
[image]

I wanted to contact Felix support team but there is no such information. I was wondering
if someone ever used felix-cloud on their Heroku app and if yes, what did you do different?

This is a very rare and special case where for file storage it's not feasible to use AWS S3 or other similar solutions, but it's rather required through a Heroku add-on.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Pollongz no, I didn't unfortunately. You may get an AWS S3 solution for storage and combine it with this add-on https://elements.heroku.com/addons/filepicker